# Creating a solution label for an exercise using \declaretheoremstyle

Tags: amsthm, thmtools, exercises, xsim

I am writing a book with exercises scattered throughout the text, for which solutions are presented at the end of each chapter.

I want the layout to be as follows:

An `exercise` environment is introduced inside the text. A solution to this exercise would later appear in the "Solution to exercises" section at the end of the chapter.

In addition, at the end of the `exercise` environment would be a page reference to the page where its solution is labeled.

A visual example (made artificially) is this:

[image]

And the last section of the chapter would be

[image]

Is it possible to do that using the [`amsthm`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) and [`thmtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) packages?

I would assume that the "Solution on page xx" string would be the value of the `postfoothook` key of the `\declaretheoremstyle` command of `thmtools`, but I don't know how to additionally insert a `label` into that value.

Maybe I am going too far, but I am also open for a way to do that using one of the [`exercise`](https://ctan.org/topic/exercise) packages ([`xsim`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xsim) looks the most promising one). I just haven't stumbled upon this exact layout.

---

### EDIT:

Since the final document is to be typeset in LyX, I think that a better way to achieve my goal is not to work with `xsim`, since for referencing, LyX works with the basic building stones of LaTeX - `label`, `pageref` and their friends.

I think that an appropriate code to be inserted into `postfoothook` and `heading` would do the job, but this is where I am asking for help:

The exercises and solutions labels would be in the following format:

- `ex:ch1:ratio-of-odd-numbers` <-> `sol:ex:ch1:ratio-of-odd-numbers`
- `ex:ch2:rolling-n-sided-die`  <-> `sol:ex:ch2:rolling-n-sided-die`
- `ex:ch2:the-hotel-problem` <-> `sol:ex:ch2:the-hotel-problem`

What I need is to refer to `sol:⟨the exrecise label⟩` inside `postfoothook` in exercise, and to refer to `⟨the exrecise label⟩` in the heading of solution.

```
\begin{exercise}\label{ex:ch1:every-prime}
blah blah
\end{exercise}
```

for which a solution is in the format

```
\begin{solution}\label{sol:ex:ch1:every-prime}
Solution to blah blah.
\end{solution}
```

1. To produce the ref "Solution on page xx" I need to concatenate `sol:` with `⟨the exrecise label⟩` to produce

```
\pageref{sol:⟨the exrecise label⟩}
```

where, in this example, `⟨the exrecise label⟩` is `ex:every-prime` (to create `\pageref{sol:ex:ch1:every-prime}`).

2. To produce the header "Solution to Exercise xx" I need to remove the `sol:` part from the `solution` label to produce `\ref{⟨the exrecise label⟩}`,  so in this example it would be, `\ref{ex:ch1:every-prime}`.

Any help about that?

A MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,hyperref,amsthm,thmtools}
%%
\declaretheoremstyle[
postfoothook = \rightline{Solution on page \pageref{sol:⟨the exrecise label⟩}
]{exercise}
\declaretheorem[style=exercise]{exercise}

\declaretheoremstyle[
heading = Solution to Exercise \ref{⟨the solution label without "sol:"⟩},
numbered=no,
]{solution}
\declaretheorem[style=solution]{solution}
%%
\begin{document}

\chapter{Prime numbers}
Lorem ipsum
\section{Dolor sit amet}
Consectetur adipiscing elit.

\begin{exercise}[Euclid]{ex:ch1:every-prime}
Prove that for every prime $p$, there is a prime $p^\prime > p$. In particular, the list of primes, $2, 3, 5, 7, \ldots$ , is infinite.
\end{exercise}

\section{Solution to exercises}
\begin{solution}\label{sol:ex:ch1:every-prime}
The proof is straight forward. First note that...
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

---

### Edit 2

As a follow up to muzimuzhi Z answer, I would like also to add an "Exercise with no solution" to my book. This environment may be named `exercise-nosol` and I want it to share the same counter with the `exercise` environment defined in the accepted answer.

How to do that?

That is, how to define the two environments (`exercise` with `xsim`, `exercise-nosol` with `thmtool`) so that they share the same counter?

I defined it using `thmtools` as follows:

```latex
\declaretheoremstyle[
postfoothook = \rightline{(No Solution) $\blacktriangleleft$}
]{exercise-nosol}
\declaretheorem[name=Exercise,numberwithin=chapter,style=exercise]{exercise}
```

output:
[image]

Comment: I am writing a textbook in Lyx and deciding the package to use for exercises. I do not require the page numbers. I only need to print the answers at the end of the book. Can I use xsim? Please refer to the full question in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631983/does-lyx-support-exercises-throughout-the-text-of-a-textbook-whose-solutions-are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `xsim` attempt, based on the "Example 5: Crossreferencing between problems and answers" shown in package manual.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xsim,lipsum,hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\DeclareExerciseHeadingTemplate{custom}
  {\section{\XSIMexpandcode{\XSIMtranslate{default-heading}}}}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}
  {%
    \IfInsideSolutionTF
      {\label{sol:\ExerciseID}}
      {\label{ex:\ExerciseID}}%
    \paragraph*
      {%
        \XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}%
        \IfInsideSolutionTF
          {
            to \GetExerciseParameter{exercise-name}%
            ~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}%
            ~(From Page~\pageref{ex:\ExerciseID})
          }
          {%
            ~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}%
            \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{~(\PropertyValue)}
          }%
      }%
  }
  {%
    \IfInsideSolutionF
      {\par\leavevmode\hfill
       Solution on page~\pageref{sol:\ExerciseID}~$\blacktriangleleft$}%
  }
\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = custom ,
  solution/template = custom ,
  print-solutions/headings-template = custom
}

\begin{document}

\section{Exercises}
\begin{exercise}[subtitle=title]
  \lipsum[1][2]
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  \lipsum[1][2]
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}[subtitle=second title]
  \lipsum[4]
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{solution}

\clearpage
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image: xsim output - exercise part]

[image: xsim output - solution part]

**Update: Support no-solution exercises**

To avoid possible incompatibilities, here is an `xsim`-only attempt.

A new command `\IfSolutionEmptyTF` is provided which uses `xsim` internal `\xsim_attribute_get:nn`. This might not be the most robust way.

I've tried `xsim`'s `\IfExistSolutionTF` and it seems to not work as I expected. Also probably due to an `xsim` issue (see [`cgnieder/xsim#90`](https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim/issues/90)), currently you have to provide an empty solution environment for each of no-solution exercises, like

```tex
\begin{solution} % no empty lines in env contents
\end{solution}
```

Full example

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xsim,lipsum,hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_empty:nTF {e}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfSolutionEmptyTF}{}
  {
    \tl_if_empty:eTF
      {
        \exp_args:Ne \xsim_attribute_get:nn
          {exercise!\ExerciseID} {solution-body}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareExerciseHeadingTemplate{custom}
  {\section{\XSIMexpandcode{\XSIMtranslate{default-heading}}}}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom-exercise}
  {%
    \label{ex:\ExerciseID}%
    \paragraph*
      {%
        % typset "Exercise <num> (<subtitle>)"
        \XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}%
        ~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}%
        \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{~(\PropertyValue)}
      }%
  }
  {%
      \par\leavevmode\hfill
      % typeset "Solution on page <page>" or "(No solution)"
      \ifcsname r@sol:\ExerciseID\endcsname
        Solution on page~\pageref{sol:\ExerciseID}%
      \else
        (No Solution)%
      \fi
      ~$\blacktriangleleft$%
  }

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom-solution}
  {%
    \IfSolutionEmptyTF{}
    {
      \label{sol:\ExerciseID}
      \paragraph*
        {%
          \XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}
          to \GetExerciseParameter{exercise-name}%
          ~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}%
          ~(From Page~\pageref{ex:\ExerciseID})
        }%
    }
  }{%
    \par
  }
\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = custom-exercise ,
  solution/template = custom-solution ,
  print-solutions/headings-template = custom
}

\begin{document}

\section{Exercises}
\begin{exercise}[subtitle=title]
  \lipsum[1][2]
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  \lipsum[1][2]
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}[subtitle=no solution]
  \lipsum[3][1] aaa
\end{exercise}
% You still need to provide an empty solution environment.
\begin{solution}
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}[subtitle=third title]
  \lipsum[4][1-3]
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  \lipsum[4][4-6]
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}[subtitle=fourth title]
  \lipsum[4][1-3]
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  \lipsum[4][4-6]
\end{solution}

\clearpage
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image: xsim output 2 - exercise part]
[image: xsim output 2 - solution part]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I prefer a way to achieve such a layout by typesetting the document in the LyX editor. I think it is too complicated to get it inside LyX with modules.

Comment: I add my upvoted

Comment: @tush The difficulty here is how to make a solution env aware of which exercise it is linked to. And I doubt LyX would preview such utilities successfully.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thanks a lot for your answer! There is only one thing I would like to add to my book. Please see my addition to the question.

Comment: @tush Answer updated.

Comment: The “hack” is not needed any more: Issue #90 is fixed and `\IfExistSolution(TF)` works

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use the `exsheets` package which conveniently allows the placement of solutions at the end of a chapter with the `\printsolutions[chapter]` command. We can label each question (and solution) for page numbering and linking using the provided `\CurrentQuestionID`. I chose to label the questions `Q:\CurrentQuestionID` and the answers `A:\CurrentQuestionID`.

In order to style the questions and solutions similar to your example, we define a new command `\problem` which takes in the `<subtitle><question text><solution>` and passes it to `exsheets`'s `question` and `solution` environment and handles the basic formatting.

Obviously the document needs to be compiled twice for the page references.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{headings = runin}
\newcommand\problem[3]{
    \begin{question}
        \textbf{(#1)} \label{Q:\CurrentQuestionID} #2
        \begin{flushright} Solution on page \pageref{A:\CurrentQuestionID} \LEFTarrow \end{flushright}
    \end{question} 
    \begin{solution}[name = Solution to exercise]
        \textbf{(From Page  \pageref{Q:\CurrentQuestionID})}
        \label{A:\CurrentQuestionID} #3
    \end{solution}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Prime Numbers}
\section{Dolor sit amet}

\problem{Euclid}{
Prove that for every prime $p$, there is a prime $p^\prime > p$. In particular, the list of primes, $2, 3, 5, 7, \ldots$ , is infinite.
}{The proof is straight forward. First note that...}

\problem{Fermat}{
$a^n+b^n=c^n$}{The proof is too large to fit on this page}

\section{Solutions}
\printsolutions[chapter]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is doable in LyX. Under `Documents>Settings>LaTeX Preamble` enter the preamble and while in that settings pane change `documentclass` to book (or something else with chapters. Then you just enter the `\problem` in LaTeX code in LyX as shown. The output is the same as above.

[image]

Comment: Can I choose not to see the Latex code on your Lyx screen but to see equations in the usual Lyx UI way? Is Lyx fully compatible with xsim? Thank you!

Comment: I posted a new question related to the above in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631983/does-lyx-support-exercises-throughout-the-text-of-a-textbook-whose-solutions-are

Answer (score 2):

With `exercise` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mwe}% <--- for testing purpose only

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}% you must load it before the exercise package
\usepackage{exercise}
%\counterwithin{Exercise}{chapter} This line if you want exercise 1.1, 1.2, etc. in chapter 1
%\counterwithin{Answer}{chapter}
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{Exercise}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent\bfseries\ExerciseName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB\ (\ExerciseTitle)}
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{Solution to exercise}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\noindent\bfseries\AnswerName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB\  (From Page \textcolor{red}{\pageref{\AnswerRef}})}
\setlength{\ExerciseSkipBefore}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\AnswerSkipBefore}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\ExerciseSkipAfter}{0pt}
\setlength{\AnswerSkipAfter}{\baselineskip}
\AfterEndEnvironment{Exercise}{\hspace{\fill}
Solution on page \textcolor{red}{\pageref{\ExerciseLabel-Answer}} $\blacktriangleleft$\vspace{\baselineskip}\par}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Prime numbers}
Lorem ipsum
\section{Dolor sit amet}
Consectetur adipiscing elit.

\begin{Exercise}[title={Euclid},label={ex:ch1:every-prime}]
Prove that for every prime $p$, there is a prime $p^\prime > p$. In particular, the list of primes, $2, 3, 5, 7, \ldots$ , is infinite.
\end{Exercise}

\blindtext% <--- for testing purpose only

\begin{Exercise}[title={Another one},label={ex:ch1:second}]
Prove that ducks are the best.
\end{Exercise}
\blindtext% <--- for testing purpose only

\section{Solution to Exercises}
\begin{Answer}[ref=ex:ch1:every-prime]
The proof is straight forward. First note that...
\end{Answer}
\blindtext% <--- for testing purpose only
\begin{Answer}[ref=ex:ch1:second]
The proof is straight forward. First note that...
\end{Answer}
\blindtext% <--- for testing purpose only

\chapter{Second chapter}
Lorem ipsum

\section{A section}
Consectetur adipiscing elit.

\begin{Exercise}[title={An exercise},label={ex:ch2:an-ex}]
Prove that something is true.
\end{Exercise}

\blindtext% <--- for testing purpose only

\begin{Exercise}[title={Another one again},label={ex:ch2:second}]
Prove that ducks are the best of all.
\end{Exercise}

\section{Solution to Exercises}
\blindtext% <--- for testing purpose only

\begin{Answer}[ref=ex:ch2:an-ex]
The proof of the first.
\end{Answer}

\blindtext% <--- for testing purpose only

\begin{Answer}[ref=ex:ch2:second]
The proof of the second.
\end{Answer}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the Section with the answers contains only the answers, you can also use `answerdelayed` and print all the answers together with `\shipoutAnswer`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mwe}% <--- for testing purpose only

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}% you must load it before the exercise package
\usepackage[answerdelayed, lastexercise]{exercise}
%\counterwithin{Exercise}{chapter} This line if you want exercise 1.1, 1.2, etc. in chapter 1
%\counterwithin{Answer}{chapter}
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{Exercise}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent\bfseries\ExerciseName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB\ (\ExerciseTitle)}
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{Solution to exercise}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\noindent\bfseries\AnswerName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB\  (From Page \textcolor{red}{\pageref{\AnswerRef}})}
\setlength{\ExerciseSkipBefore}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\AnswerSkipBefore}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\ExerciseSkipAfter}{0pt}
\setlength{\AnswerSkipAfter}{\baselineskip}
\AfterEndEnvironment{Exercise}{\hspace{\fill}
Solution on page \textcolor{red}{\pageref{\ExerciseLabel-Answer}} $\blacktriangleleft$}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Prime numbers}
Lorem ipsum
\section{Dolor sit amet}
Consectetur adipiscing elit.

\begin{Exercise}[title={Euclid},label={ex:ch1:every-prime}]
Prove that for every prime $p$, there is a prime $p^\prime > p$. In particular, the list of primes, $2, 3, 5, 7, \ldots$ , is infinite.
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
The proof is straight forward. First note that...
\end{Answer}

\blindtext% <--- for testing purpose only

\begin{Exercise}[title={Another one},label={ex:ch1:second}]
Prove that ducks are the best.
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
The proof is straight forward. First note that...
\end{Answer}
\blindtext% <--- for testing purpose only

\section{Solution to Exercises}
\shipoutAnswer

\chapter{Second chapter}
Lorem ipsum

\section{A section}
Consectetur adipiscing elit.

\begin{Exercise}[title={An exercise},label={ex:ch2:an-ex}]
Prove that something is true.
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
The proof of the first.
\end{Answer}

\blindtext% <--- for testing purpose only

\begin{Exercise}[title={Another one again},label={ex:ch2:second}]
Prove that ducks are the best of all.
\end{Exercise}%
\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
The proof of the second.
\end{Answer}

\section{Solution to Exercises}
\shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which package is best to use with Lyx, "exercise" or "xsim"?

Comment: I posted a new question related to the above in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631983/does-lyx-support-exercises-throughout-the-text-of-a-textbook-whose-solutions-are

Comment: @RodolfoOviedo You can use them both with LyX.

Comment: Many thanks, Carla! Would you answer (part of) the question in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631983/does-lyx-support-exercises-throughout-the-text-of-a-textbook-whose-solutions-are?